# How to Use KeyEventListener for a JTextArea and use Tab to autocomplete word from a list

Tags: java, swing

I want to get text input from a user (from JTextArea) and use autocomplete based on a pre-existing list.

E.g. User would type 'London Vict' and press TAB which would then complete to London Victoria (this would be contained within a list).

I am struggling to get back the user's text, I have tried adding a KeyEventListener to the JTextArea but I had no luck.

Please find the code below:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class View extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    Map.Entry<String, List<Integer> > entry = new MyEntry<String, List<Integer> >("London Victoria", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2)));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    View frame = new View();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public View() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTextArea StationDetails = new JTextArea();
        StationDetails.setText("Enter Undergound Name: ");
        StationDetails.setBounds(35, 19, 382, 232);
        //StationDetails.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener);
        contentPane.add(StationDetails);
    }

    final class MyEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
        private final K key;
        private V value;

        public MyEntry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V value) {
            V old = this.value;
            this.value = value;
            return old;
        }
    }

}
```

The List which contains all the station names is called 'entry'

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean by no luck with the key event listener? You might want to look at creating a KeyMap, but you would do a similar thing as the event listener, it just would probably work better.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most are correct, but not all. Be consistent!!!

> User would type 'London Vict' and press TAB

Swing components use an `Key Bindings` to map an `Action` to a `KeyStroke`.

Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for some basics. There are sections on:

1. How to Use Key Bindings
2. How to Use Actions

Your key binding code would look something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 30);
InputMap im = textArea.getInputMap();
KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB");
textArea.getActionMap().put(im.get(tab), new TabAction(true));
```

And your TabAction would be something like:

```
class TabAction extends AbstractAction
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextArea textArea = (JTextArea)e.getSource();

        //  get the word at the caret
        //  lookup the full word
        //  replace current text with full word
    }
}
```

You can use the `Utilities` class to help you get the starting offset of the text you want to replace and then use the `replaceSelection` method of the JTextArea to replace the text once you lookup the word.